# Screen goes black after trying to access BIOS Setup

Tags: boot, bios, uefi

I've been trying to access my BIO settings, in order to change the boot order to boot from USB first.

When booting the computer and holding down F12, the BIOS menu comes up fine, and I can access the "Device Configuration" and "Change Boot Mode Settings" options, but when I select "BIOS Setup" or "Diagnostics" the screen turns black.

I've waited up to 5 minutes to see if the menu is just slow, but nothing happens. Eventually, I just turn off the computer and reboot.

I've also tried selecting "Shift/Restart -> Troubleshooting -> Advanced Options -> UEFI Firmware Settings" while booted in Windows to access this menu and I also get a black screen.

To be clear, Windows boots perfectly. I just cannot access the BIOS/UEFI settings.

I'm on a brand spanking new Dell Precision 5820 Tower with Intel Xeon W-2102 and Windows 10. The current boot mode is "UEFI, secure boot on".

Comment: I would consult with Dell Support, 'cause it sure sounds like they sold you some badware which needs fixin' or replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tower has two display ports. It turns out that only one of them was active in the BIOS menu, but both were active at all other times. Switching the monitor to the other port solved the problem.

Comment: This post right here ended a two week struggle of trying to figure out why the fiancee's computer would always "fail" to load into BIOS when Windows Update stopped working. If you're ever in Omaha, hit us up. We owe you one!

Comment: i updated to a rtx 3080 asus tuf oc 10gb and now i cant see my bios anymore.i got a asrock z270 extreme 4. after cmos reset still blackscreen, tired out all hdmi, dvi, vga and DP, still black. Installed the old 1060 GTX and i got into the bios. Updated the bios to the latest version 2.7

Comment: @StefanHöltker I had the same issue with "asrock b550 phantom gaming 4". Only once after resetting bios I'd be able to get in, but mostly just black screen (no other port worked) with the 2060 GTX. I reset the bios again and then updated to 2.71 BIOS on the first chance and it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer if neither of the current ones work: I have a VR headset, and that plugs into the GPU as well. After troubleshooting for quite a while, I realised that the BIOS was being shown in that, and not my monitor! Unplugging the VR's HDMI cable fixed it.

Comment: Changing BIOS settings using a VR headset. What an experience!